# Discrepancies Between Core Data Editor and NSManagedObjectSublcass

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

How are discrepancies between the Core Data Editor and the custom NSManagedObject subclass handled by Xcode?

For instance, let's say in the editor I have and Entity called `Person` with attributes `firstName` and `age`. I then create an NSManagedObject subclass of `Person` from the editor and in the header of the subclass I add the attribute `lastName` but I don't update the editor with this new attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Depends somewhat on exactly how you define the property, but usually it will be treated like a transient property, so its value will not be set when the object is retrieved from the store unless you write some custom code to set it, nor will Core Data make any attempt to save it to the store.  Also you won't be able to use the property in any fetch or sort predicate that results in core data generating sqlite SQL calls.